# How to determine the options Linux kernel was build with?

Tags: linux, kernel, configuration, options, procfs

Say, I have custom kernel from my distribution, how could I get list of all options the kernel was build with?

It's possible to get them by reading config file from kernel package from vendor's repo, but is there any other way? I mean ways to get that information form the kernel itself, maybe from procfs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what @Stephen Kitt said, at least on my Debian system you can find the information in:

```
/boot/config-<version>
```

Where version, in my case, is:

```
3.16.0-4-686-pae
```

So, issuing:

```
less /boot/config-3.16.0-4-686-pae
```

Spits out the kernel configs in a **long** list!

Answer (score 6):

If your kernel was built with [`IKCONFIG_PROC`](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/init/Kconfig#n816) enabled, you'll be able to retrieve the configuration from `/proc/config.gz`. If it was built with [`IKCONFIG`](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/init/Kconfig#n803) enabled, you'll be able to extract it from the kernel image using the [`extract-ikconfig`](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/scripts/extract-ikconfig) script.

If neither configuration option is enabled, you'll need to read the configuration file from the vendor's repository.

Comment: Thanks, this is were I found the config in an Android device.